# PHP Prep. Stmt - What is wrong?

Tags: php

I'm trying to learn PHP with prepared statements and I have had some frustrating errors before but I figured them out by myself ( after 4 frustrating hours ). Now i'm getting this error : 
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in .... on line 15.

```
<?php
$host="127.0.0.1";
$port=3306;
$socket="";
$user="root";
$password="";
$dbname="ewt";

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());

$mysqli = $con;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO PERSOON VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssid',$firstName,$lastName,$email,$pass,$address,$city,$zip,$telephone);

$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

I have absolutely no idea what's wrong with the code.

Comment: Did you try looking for [errors](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)?

Comment: Probably, your `prepare` is failing and returning `false` so your `bind` won't work. Should `PERSOON` be `PERSON`?

Comment: This happens when one does not implement error handling but blindly relies on "thing going right usually". You must _test_ if the `prepare()` call actually is successful before going on!

Comment: And you are using mysqls `root` account for normal usage and even without a password! Don't!

Comment: @Mike W: I'm dutch so it's PERSOON.

Comment: @arkascha: This is my VERY first time trying to learn PHP so i'm sorry ...? And this is purely for test purposes locally. I'm aware i shouldn't use it without a pass :)

Comment: Using identifiers (variables, column names, etc.) in your native language when writing code that is inherently based on English is just setting yourself up for trouble, unfortunately...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol The whole web app is English. Only the database is in dutch ( My other project members did this :( )

Comment: Theoretically, this should work. @user3511568 Are your form elements named and no typos? I.e.: `<input type="text" name="firstName">` Plus, POST variables are case-sensitive, therefore `firstName` is not the same as `firstname` so double-check everything. When ONE fails, your whole query will fail.

Comment: Nope, i've double checked everything! I usually use the noncapitalCapital so I don't think it's that.

Comment: All your columns exist, no spaces in them? Example column name `first name` should not be used, use as one word or use an underscore. Also, it's recommended to use actual column names. 
Example: `INSERT INTO PERSOON (firstName,lastName,email...) VALUES (...)` etc. so if a column does not exist or has spaces or is mistyped, that is another possible problem. @user3511568 Again, if ONE of anything fails, everything will fail. Show us your table structure.

Comment: I noticed in your comment below *"Alrighty! I update my code and now i'm getting: Undefined index: pass in ... at the $pass = $_POST['pass']; section. I'll try to figure this out and find a solution! Thanks in advance for your help! Its highly appreciated"* See what I said earlier? Your password input is either not named, or is mispelled. @user3511568 --- Always include your form when asking a question; it leaves the guesswork out of things. ;-) If that's the issue, I should be getting the credit for this. The other person has not asked enough questions in order to find the actual problem.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm SUCH A MORON. In my register page i have 2 fields : pass1 and pass2. In my PHP i said PASS. That was my mistake! I'm litteraly facepalming ... Everything works now. I'll work on error messaging now. Thanks dude!

Comment: You're welcome, and don't be so hard on yourself, things happen like that. I'm just glad you were able to resolve this. @user3511568 Next time (*let's hope there isn't one*), post your form lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- I will :D ! It's just frustrating because this is a school project and a important one. It's my very first time working on a WebApp since I only have been working with programming languages like c# and java. I have found my motivation again ... After 6 hours :p

Comment: Great @user3511568 I know the feeling, believe me. I just hope you don't end up spending **3 days** on a problem lol!, which happened to me on a few occasions (*yes, days*), however I am a **very determined** person when it comes to fixing anything (be it code, or motorcycles) ;-), including for "others", such as yours (*code of course*). Cheers mate.

Answer (score 2):

I spy two possible problems, and one irrelevant but important problem that will immediately bite you as soon as you fix the possible problems.

1. I doubt your table name is `PERSOON`. `PERSON`, maybe.
2. I also doubt your table has exactly eight columns. Or if it does, you don't have an ID column which is a really bad idea to be missing.

In either of these cases, your `prepare()` call will return `false`, which is obviously not an object. You would be able to determine the exact error using `var_dump($mysqli->error);`

And the important problem: You are attempting to use all your extracted `$_POST` variables *before* you declare them...

Comment: You don't need to pass the `id` column if it is `autoincrement`.

Comment: @steffen Correct, but in this case OP is not declaring the list of columns whose values are to be set, therefore the query assumes that all columns are being set in order - a very bold and usually wrong assumption!

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply. I'm dutch so I have written my db tables in dutch. It's Persoon haha. I have changed the INSERT to $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO PERSOON (VOORNAAM,NAAM,EMAIL,WACHTWOORD,ADRES,WOONPLAATS,POSTCODE,TELEFOONNUMMER) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

Comment: Gotcha, but I'm sure you understand why it seemed like a typo ;) In this case, then, I'm certain that it's because your number of values does not match the number of columns. Check `$mysqli->error` for details.

Comment: Alrighty! I update my code and now i'm getting:  Undefined index: pass in ... at the $pass = $_POST['pass']; section. I'll try to figure this out and find a solution! Thanks in advance for your help! Its highly appreciated